# I commited a file that's over github's file size limit. How do fix this commit without losing progress?

Tags: git, github

I was working on a project and commited all changes to my local branch. When I tried to push to github I got denied because one of the new files created on my repo was over the default filesize limit. Now even if I remove the offending file and do a new commit I can't push to the repo, since a version of that file is on my branch history.

How can I remove this file from the existing commit without losing all changes done to other files?

I'm thinking of branching the previous commit, merging both except for the new file, but I'm not experienced enough to do it with confidence, so if anyone is willing to write out a step by step I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't the place to ask for a basic Git tutorial. Your idea is sound, though. Or, instead of branching, just reset the branch to the commit (a destructive act) and re-commit without the file. Depends on how much work was done since.

Comment: You didn't explicitly state this, but you implied that the file was added in your last commit. If that's the case, at that point if you had amended that commit instead of creating a new commit, it would have worked. If you now are in a state where your top two commits are the adding and then a removal of the file, then [Jon_Kle's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73748111/184546) should work. Reset soft back to 3 commits ago, notice the big file is not staged, and then commit. This will make a new commit that replaces your current top 2. (This is identical to squashing the top 2 into 1.)

Answer (score 0):

the command `git reset --soft` resets the commit history to the last commit without changing or deleting files in the working directory. From there, just recommit all the files you want to have in the commit.